# Where should a Google Service Account be created? The App's domain? Or in each client's Domain?

Tags: google-oauth, service-accounts

Is a Service Account intended to be created in an application’s domain? Or in a clients G Suite Domain, on behalf of the application?

---

Background:
My company has a product (hereafter “The App”) which has several thousand organizations as clients, each potentially having their own Google domains. (hereafter “Organization Domain”)

We are looking to set up a sync between The App and the Organization Domain, for data that is common between The App and the Organization Domain, and want to use an OAuth2 connection, with a domain admin granting The App ‘domain-wide authority’ on behalf of their users, for offline syncing.

From the [Service Account page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount):

> ... an account that belongs to your application instead of to an
>   individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of
>   the service account, so users aren't directly involved.

and

> G Suite domain administrators can also grant service accounts
>   domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the
>   domain.

Referencing the [Cloud Platform Console Help Faq](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en):

> You can access data from your users' Google Cloud Platform projects by
>   creating a service account to represent your service, and then having
>   your customers grant that service account appropriate access to their
>   cloud data using IAM policies. Note that you *might* want to create a
>   service account per customer... (emphasis added)

It sounds like The App should be able to create a single Service Account, which all of our clients authenticate into for their Organization Domain.

The part that’s unclear:
In the Service Account page, the instructions for delegating domain wide authority seems to shift concerning where the Service Account is.
Before the instructions, it reads:

> ... first enable domain-wide delegation for *an existing service
>   account* in the Service accounts page ... with domain-wide delegation
>   enabled. Then, an administrator *of the G Suite domain* must complete
>   the following steps:

Afterwards, it reads

> Your application now has the authority to make API calls *as users in
>   your domain* (to "impersonate" users). (emphasis added)

From what I’m reading, the first part reads "one Service Account for The App", while the later reads as "the service account is only able to access as a person on The App domain, rather than the Organization Domain."

Is a service account intended to be created in The App's domain? Or in the Organization Domain, on behalf of The App?

I have seen examples that have the Organization Domain admin create a service account, and then pass over the clientID/secret to the owners of The App… but I’m not sure that’s the correct approach for our scenario.

---

Related - Scope management:
The delegation steps have the Organization Domain admin manually add scopes.

We’d prefer to use the OAuth consent screen, which shows the scopes, and has our pages/policies linked. 
Unfortunately, as far as my research has uncovered, it doesn’t look like that page is used in the Service Account authorization flow; just for other application types, which authenticate a single user, as opposed to an entire Organization Domain.

Is there a page I’ve missed in Google’s sea of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss understanding the use of Service accounts.

Service accounts are dummy user accounts.  They have their own drive account, calendar account and probably a few more.   Service accounts are designed for use with back end applications server to server communication where there is no user interaction.   Service accounts are preauthorized.  You grant the service account access to the user data in your case by using domain wide dedication to the gsuite account. This way the service account would be able to for example send control all the users google calendar accounts.

This is why you dont need a consent screen. Another point with service accounts is you must control the data in order to set this up.  If you dont control the data then you cant grant the service account access to that data.

You should be using Oauth2 if you want to access private user data owned by your customers.

As for the rest of your question is very broad and i am not really user where to start with it you might want to break it up into several questions.  Take them one at a time.  I am not sure i understand what it is you are trying to do so i dont think i can try to answer that part.

Comment: My core question is whether the Service Account can _only_ operate on the one Domain it's created in, or if there's a way for the SA to be domain wide delegated to from a different (user) domain. (Based on the docs, if there is, it's through a manual setup using the Service Account ID in the client's admin console, to give the preauthorization)

Comment: My followup (the 'related' section) only really matters if the Service Account _can_ be set up once and then referenced from multiple user domains. eg: if that's possible, I'd like to know if there's a better way of setting the scopes other than manually typing them in the Admin console.

Comment: you can set it up to as many user domains you have access to but you will have to do it manually in the console